# Count the amount of values in the table c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I got a structure

```
struct number{
int value;
};

number numbers[1000];
```

I have a for loop to input the values and breakoff when the user decides to leave adding panel, that feature works fine. I got another for loop for displaying the entered data which does the job (kind of) as it requires me to use system("pause"); otherwise the loop constantly enters everything within the function including the couts that are outside of the loop.

```
void ListNumbers(){
    system("cls");
    cout << "\t\t\tArray: Numbers" << endl;;
    cout << "Value" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        if (NULL == numbers[i].value)
            break;
        cout << numbers[i].value << endl;


    }
    cout << "\n\nAmount of records: " << sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]) << endl;
    system("pause");
```

I want the program to list the amount of records/indexes in the table that are currently filled with data. Currently it displays the total amount of records in the database (being 1000). Also if possible, method for fixing the display loop so I am not required to use the system pause would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Keep count of records as the user enters them, and when you print them out, only print as many as were entered. Better still, use a `std::vector` instead of an array, and it'll keep count of how many items it contains.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be checking integer value check as :

```
 if (NULL == numbers[i].value)
```

have a well defined intention like :

```
  if (0 == numbers[i].value)
```

Use std::vectors for creating dynamic array, do not restrict yourself to size of 1000.

And statement :

```
cout << "\n\nAmount of records: " <<sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0])
```

You are taking sizeof numbers array divided by sizeof 1st numbers element. This division is constant and will only vary depending sizeof(int).

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you break out of the loop after finding the first NULL which is inconsistent with what you've said that you want.  You should be incrementing a counter for each non-NULL value by using an if..else.  You don't want to break because you want the loop to check every single entry within the table.  In the cout outside of the loop, you display the counter that you have been incrementing.  You can use some basic math to determine the count of NULL variables.  Your use of the sizeof seems strange since you already know that the array is 1000.  That is just a fancy way of producing the number 1000 which you could have just stored within a constant and reused.

I cannot understand why you think that you need a system pause.  I cannot see the rest of the program so I assume that you want to pause before the console window closes.  Well you could just start a command prompt and simply run the exe from a cmd window.  Then it won't close.  It closes because when you run from the debugger, the IDE will close the console after it finishes running the program.  Depending on your IDE, there may be a solution for that but you need to tell us what IDE that you are using or just google search the issue with that IDE name within your search.

Comment: I use the system pause because without it the display function starts to loop endlessly. Don't know how to fix it. I figured out a way to do it, now once the NULL value is met, if will display cout<<"Amount of records: "<< i; and then break which seems to be working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want the following:

- Output the valid items.
- Count the valid items.
- Count all the items.

I would typically implement what I think you want like this:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct number
{
  int value;
};

std::ostream& operator << ( std::ostream& os, const number& n )
{
  return os << n.value;
}

number numbers[] = { {1}, {0}, {2}, {0}, {3}, {0}, {4}, {0} };

template <class T, std::size_t N>
T* begin( T (&array)[N] )
{
  return array;
}
template <class T, std::size_t N>
T* end( T (&array)[N] )
{
  return array+N;
}

template <class T, std::size_t N>
std::size_t itemCount( T (&array)[N] )
{
  return N;
}


bool is_zero( const number& n ){ return( n.value == 0 ); }
bool is_not_zero( const number& n ){ return( !is_zero( n ) ); }

void listNumbers()
{
  std::cout << "Valid values are:" << std::endl;
  std::remove_copy_if( begin( numbers ), end( numbers ),
    std::ostream_iterator<number>(std::cout, "\t" ), is_zero );
  std::cout << std::endl;

  std::iterator_traits<number*>::difference_type count =
    std::count_if( begin( numbers ), end( numbers ), is_not_zero );
  std::cout << "There is " << count
            << " items with valid values out of a possible sequence of "
            << itemCount( numbers ) << "." << std::endl;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  listNumbers();
  return 0;
}
```

I've thrown in a couple of typical c++ concepts that you might consider e.g the use of standard algorithms to do the work for you. I would personally use a vector instead of an array, and binders with member functions (or a lambda) to check whether values are not zero (or visa versa), but I've used the array and some non member functions for you to get the idea.

Comment: Apologies to the OP that I've not read the question well. I've modified my solution to use the structure <number>.

Comment: Your method might work but it suprpases my skill in C++ I have right know by significant margin. I must fully understand the solutions to the problems I have, but I gave you an upvote for lots of effort you put in! //Edit, damn I cant even give upvotes :/